# SignalR aspNet core .Net WPF Client is not connecting to server in production Environment

Tags: wpf, asp.net-core, signalr, asp.net-core-signalr, signalr-2

I'm using WPF with asp.net core as sever, for client & server communications we have implemented signalR framework.

It is connecting seamlessly when I'm running project through Visual studio / development environment. When I take setup for WPF application it throughs below exception shown in screen shot.

[image]

I have corrected all the package versions, related to asp.net core, signalR core for client and server, all are under same version specified by Microsoft documentation.

[Difference between aspnet SignalR and AspNet Core SignalR](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/signalr/version-differences?view=aspnetcore-2.1)

Versions I'm using

[image]

[image]

Can any one help me on this.

Comment: did you check if you can open network port between your servers ?

Comment: does firewall block access?

Comment: I did specify any port, so it should be 80, which will be always opened

Comment: Did the client and server on the same computer? Try to make a test with running client on the signalr server to check whether it is related with network.

Comment: Yes, Client and server on same computer

Comment: I found the problem, I have missed some dependencies related to Task extensions  while preparing WIX setup for deployment